React - dependency arrays with context providers
Say I have something like this:
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface ChannelProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const ChannelContext = createContext<{ channelId: string, setChannelId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> } | null>(null);

export const ChannelProvider = ({ children }: ChannelProviderProps) => {
  const [channelId, setChannelId] = useState<string>('Initial');
  return (
    <ChannelContext.Provider value={{ channelId, setChannelId }}>
      {children}
    </ChannelContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useChannel = () => {
    const context = useContext(ChannelContext);
    console.log('useChannel context is: ', context);
    if (!context) {
      const errorMessage = `Existing context not found.\n useChannel must be used within a ChannelProvider`
      throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }
    return context;
};

And I have Component A, and Component B... both of which have this provider wrapped around them:
        <ChannelProvider>
            <Component A />
        </ChannelProvider>


        <ChannelProvider>
            <Component B />
        </ChannelProvider>

If Component A has this code:
const { channelId, setChannelId } = useChannel();

useEffect(() => {
    setChannelId('SomethingElse')
}, []);

and Component B has this code:
const { channelId, setChannelId } = useChannel();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(channelId);
}, [channelId]);

If both components are mounted, will Component B print out 'Initial', or will it print 'SomethingElse'?
I'm not sure if I'm grasping this exactly. I can appreciate and understand when dependency arrays rely on the component's local states... but I'm unsure of 'remote' states.
Would Component B need to re-render in order to have awareness of this newly updated channelId?

Component A and Component B are interacting with completely different context providers. Changes to one will have no effect on the other. Is that what you wanted?

In your setup, Component A and Component B are each wrapped in their own ChannelProvider. This means:

Each ChannelProvider has its own separate channelId state.
Component A updates its own channelId to 'SomethingElse'.
Component B has a different ChannelProvider and retains its channelId as 'Initial'.

Therefore, when Component B logs channelId, it will print 'Initial' because the two components do not share the same state.

thanks for your reply, that makes sense.
the reason that they have separate provider wrappings is because we have this logic in our code:
const componentBPanel = document.getElementById('component-b-panel');
componentB = </ ChannelProvider>;
const rootElement = createRoot(sidebarPanel);
rootElement.render(sidebar);
Im guessing this is a problem if we want Component A (which is really just the rest of my app) to share ChannelProvider context with Component B.
perhaps a solution is having Comp. B invisible at start

ah. that looks terrible. hopefully you're still able to digest that and humor me with a little further advice? thank you
